# Play store - User reviews are not shared among them; each user can only see their own review

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, google-play-console, google-reviews

play console - I've noticed that user reviews are not shared among them; each user can only see their own review. What could be the solution or problem in your opinion? Thank you.

Android application
play store
play console
sdk 33

I checked on the Play Console if there are any configurations to be done, but there is nothing except the option to reply to a review or enable notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Reviews are not visible public for new apps with only a few reviews. Wait for more reviews, installs and user rating, there's nothing to do from your side.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. Is there a specific number of reviews that need to be reached to make them public?

Comment: No, afaik there's nothing known. Also: https://www.androidpolice.com/google-play-store-reviews-not-visible-right-away/

Comment: okay , that's helpful , thank you